# Elasticsearch - get specific child documents

Tags: elasticsearch

```
   question
    /    \
   /      \
comment  answer
```

If I have this document structure with join mapping (in elasticsearch 6.2.2).

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "qustion",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "no": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can get all comment&answer related to question no 1 with this query.
What if I want to get ONLY answer document, How should I change this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a condition

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
        "must":[{"has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "qustion",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "no": "1"
              }
            }
          }},{
              "type":"answer"
          }]
    }
  }
}
```